# Apple Screen Sharing = VNC/RDP?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

Is Apple Screen Sharing just an implementation of VNC/RDP or similar protocols? If so, then which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is none of them, however it is compatible with VNC.

Comment: Your quite right since OS X 10.7 Apple Screen Sharing is this Process /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/screensharingd.bundle/Contents/MacOS/screensharingd befor on OS X 10.5 and 10.6 it was /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/AppleVNCServer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleVNCServer so back then it really was just an implementation of a VNC Server

Comment: If it's neither.. what actually is it?

Comment: @konqui Do you think it could possibly be just a name change?

Comment: @tjt263 on os x 10.5/10.6 Screensharing and VNC were the same (just a possibility for Remote Login) - since 10.7 Screensharing is it's own Thing cause now it doesn't make a difference wether you enable just "Remote Login" or "Remote Management" it is the same deamon which gets launched so technically it must now be more than just vnc - i think it is a combination of vnc and rdp now