# How do you set the display correctly when SSH ing from Yosemite to Catalina?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, firefox

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-do-i-run-a-gui-app-via-ssh), except I would like to ssh from a Yosemite Mac Pro to a Catalina Mac Pro and run Firefox GUI.  So far I have tried the following:

```
user@yosemite-machine:~$ ssh -X user@catalina-machine
user@catalina-machine:~$ cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Content/MacOS
user@catalina-machine:~$ ./firefox    # <-- I wait for a minute, but no Firefox GUI
```

But if I log in directly into catalina-machine, open the terminal and navigate to cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Content/MacOS and run the firefox binary, it works (i.e. the Firefox GUI appears).

Why am I unable to see Firefox on my yosemite-machine's display after SSH'ing into  my catalina-machine ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a GUI app via SSH?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-do-i-run-a-gui-app-via-ssh)

Answer (score 3):

Because macOS is not running X11.  It is not Linux.

You've instructed `ssh` to forward X11 through a tunnel back to the original machine, but there is no X11 to forward.

Comment: so is there no way to SSH into a Catalina OS and launch a GUI like Firefox? I'm not necessarily trying to use X11, it could be by any other means.

Comment: The question you linked has a comprehensive set of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does screen sharing over the VNC ports - so you [could port forward them over ssh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30239/5472) once you've [sorted out your VNC access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84228/5472). Unless you wanted to run X11 apps - this is the way to get native apps to run remotely.

- [Remote Management vs. Screen Sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34443/)
- [Apple Screen Sharing = VNC/RDP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205262/)